# Identifying read and write serial ports in Dart for Flutter web development

Tags: flutter, dart, web

Currently, I have 2 USBs connected to 2 ports on my computer, with one of them meant to receive data and commands from surrounding devices while the other sends data to them. To read and write the data received from the USBs, I need to know which is the correct USB to read and write from, is there some way to identify them using a Dart? Thank you.

Currently, I am sending a specific write command to all the ports so I that I can then listen for a specific String as a serial port reply from them, but does not seem feasible currently.